# Created a new object, then put an array after it in a loop to patch a property, it works but I dont know why?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I'm working with JavaScript in Node.js and using Express with some mongoose and following a well known RESTful API tutorial on youtube, I've come to patching the API and have been trying to understand why the following code works for sometime now;

```
  updateItem = {};
  for (const changes of req.body) {
    updateItem[changes.propName] = changes.value;
  }
  Product.updateOne({ _id: id }, { $set: updateItem })
```

The rest is just your standard .then().catch() to send the response status, but I'm lost on how creating the object then placing it before an array works to update a value.

It's my current understanding that the object must be instantiated before use, I couldn't just put brackets there and have it work, even if I wasn't using it to set something later. Then I loop through the changes from the request body which must be an array to allow looping, but here's where I get lost.

Does the array of iterated prop names `changes.propName` get placed inside the `updateItem` object which is then set to the changed values from the array of properties that are being changed? Do I need to understand `$set` syntax more? I'm struggling to pick it apart to make it longer or simpler but better to understand.

This is the json array setup I'm passing for testing through postman if it helps;

```
[
    {
        "propName": "name", "value": "placeholder user"
    }
]
```

I was unable to find anything to help me understand the interactions going on here, I haven't seen something like this before either but please redirect me if this has already been asked.

Comment: You are not "_placing it before an array_".  `[]` used with objects are called [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Comment: first you should understand the concepts in JS. They using mongoose another challenge

Comment: @RandyCasburn So since the array is a string, dot notation can't be used? It's accessing the propName value, then setting the associated value from whatever it was before to placeholder user?